# Is there a statistical approach to determine the minimum sample size for comparison of sums over time?

Tags: time-series, sample-size, effect-size

I have the number of items sold of various products over time from a supermarket. Each product belongs to a category of products. Some categories have a large number of items sold and some categories have small numbers of items sold. This is the total population of items sold, not a sample.

[image]

I am reporting the items sold per month on a graph such as below, along with the % change of the total sales of year t vs year t-1.
[image]

I also have a business requirement to classify the trend of each product based on the below simple rule so that all business stakeholders can understand the reason for each trend classification:

- % change >= 20% : Increasing trend
- % change <= -20% : Decreasing trend
- -20% < % change < 20% : Flat trend

**Questions:**

1. Is there a statistical approach to determine a minimum number of sales per year per Category that allows for more confidence in the classification of the trend or is this purely a business decision?

For example:

- For Category A the total sales are X (e.g. 10,000), so for each product within Category A, for any results to have "meaning", the minimum number of sales per year needs to be Y (e.g. 100), where Y is some function of X
- Or determine the minimum sample size based on a statistical test (e.g. paired samples t-test?) but then still use the % change rules instead of whether the difference is significant
- Or only report the % change for differences that are significant

2. On a separate but related note, I am concerned that this simplistic rule for classifying trends is going to create misleading information such as the examples below. And if so, would it be better (better = more confident that the trend classification is not just due to random fluctuations) to determine if a trend exists through time-series analysis per product?

For example:

- For products that have very few sales the % change can jump around a lot e.g. from 10 items to 20 items it’s 100% change but the actual numbers are quite small from a business perspective
- There maybe be an outlier in one year that makes all the difference in an otherwise flat trendline